# Difference in Pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

What are the differences between these three pointers in C? I’m confused on how they differ.

```
int* arr1[8];
int (*arr2)[8];
int *(arr3[8]);
```

Comment: Two are no pointers at all. An array is not a pointer and a pointer is no array.

Answer (score 4):

```
int* arr1[8];
```

`arr1` is an array of 8 pointers to int.

```
int (*arr2)[8];
```

`arr2` is a pointer to array of 8 ints.

```
int *(arr3[8]);
```

Same as `arr1`. The brackets are superfluous.

You may want to read [Right-Left rule](http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html) on how to read complex C declarations.